# Fastest way to add computed columns in a table with billions of rows

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am not experienced in table designing and dba stuff in SQL Server. However I have a task to create an maintain a huge database with billions of rows. I have a table with below specification:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inventory](
[ProductID] [numeric](18, 3) NULL,
[RegionID] [numeric](18, 3) NULL,
[ShopCode] [int] NULL,
[QTY] [float] NULL,
[OLAPDate] [varchar](6) NULL,
[Price] [float] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The table does not have a primary key but below indexes:

```
IX_OLAPDate(Clustered)
IX_ProductID(Non-unique, Non-Clustered)
IX_RegionID(Non-unique, Non-Clustered)
IX_ShopCode(Non-unique, Non-Clustered)
```

I get a text file each month and need to insert it into table. I do this task with bcp utility.

My problem is that I need to add some calculations on these data and add them as input into python. The calculations are for example adding calculated columns with count, sum and other simple functions, but whit these amount of data, these calculations are impossible.

my system specification:
128 G RAM
32 Cores Xeon(R) 2.1GHz Processor

So what is the most efficient way to do these types of adding calculations? Does partitioning my table into monthly intervals makes these calculation faster? Can I add these calculated columns into each partition so that the memory does not that much engaged?

Should I change the structure of the table? Although this would make insertion into the original table hard, cause the text file which I receive each month is in this structure.

Any suggestion would absolutely appreciated.

Comment: `count, sum` you cannot do this in computed columns.

Comment: @Pரதீப் Your right. I mean I need to add some calculated columns based on some conditions on other columns (for example add 1 or 0 in a new column) and then group by the table and compute the counts and sums.

Comment: You can do the complete calculations once at first and then just compute the delta of the new records only.

Comment: @Pரதீப் for example adding a new column that if QTY is over that 1, put 1 and if the QTY is less than 1 , put 0 and finally sums the 1s in that column in group by.

Comment: @mpy - Ok. Does your current query utilizes any of the available index ? Post the query. Highly I doubt that computed columns gonna help you.

Comment: Possibly, you want an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @Pரதீப் select * , HaveQTY = case 
      when QTY > 1 then 1
      else 0
      end
into test 
from Inventory

Comment: @mpy So you don't have where clause. Do you really need all that billion rows every time ?

Comment: @Pரதீப் no just one time and then adding each month data to the destination.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr;** redesign your table, computed columns will be useless for you either way.

In SQL Server, computed columns are virtual columns (unless marked as persisted) - which means that they are not stored as data, but instead calculated on demand, whenever they are used in an SQL Statement.

Moreover, computed columns can only reference constant values or column values within the same row, the results of a built in function (such as `GetDate()`) - or the result of a user defined scalar function - which is what you will have to use if you want to use values from more than a single row in your computed column.
User defined scalar functions are notoriously slow, which basically means you don't have an efficient way to do what you want using computed columns.

Also, None of your indexes is a unique index, and all of your columns are nullable, which suggests a problem in the design of the table - since there can't be a primary key in such a table and there's nothing stopping your user to insert duplicate records (worst possible scenario - duplicate records where all the columns are null).

Comment: Would portioning the table a solution?

Comment: I really can't say - I don't have the details. performance tuning requires intimate knowledge of the queries, the database design, and the execution plan. All I have to go on is the table's DDL...